# Adding together CSV values in D3

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I can not seem to figure out how to parse through the CSV and get an accurate output in HTML.  My CSV has the same product listed a couple times, plus there are some combined products I need to break into their individual parts and add to their respective products.

I then need to find a way to remove those duplicates and combined products from the table display (even just adding a class to the row and hiding via css will work).

Codepen with latest code:https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/project/editor/DnaBqq

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.net_quantity = + d.net_quantity;
     });
    function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody');

    // append the header row
    thead.append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
      .data(columns).enter()
      .append('th')
        .text(function (column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('tr');

      var expensesCount = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.SKU; })
      /*.rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })*/
      .rollup(function(v) { return {
        total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.amount; })
      }; })
      .entries(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(expensesCount));

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
      .data(function (row) {
        return columns.map(function (column) {
          return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append('td')
        .text(function (d) { return d.value; });

  return table;

}

// render the table(s)
tabulate(data, ['Product Title','SKU','Monthly units','Weekly units']); // 2 column table
```

Right now, I am getting this output:

Product Title - SKU - Monthly units - Weekly units

Product One - PRD101 - 5 - 2

Product Two - PRD102 - 10 - 3

Product Three - PRD103 - 15 - 10

Product OneAndTwo - PRD201 - 30 - 5

Product One - PRD101 - 6 - 12

---

I would like to have:

Product Title - SKU - Monthly units - Weekly units

Product One - PRD101 - 41 - 19

Product Two - PRD102 - 40 - 8

Product Three - PRD103 - 15 - 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a nudge in the right direction, to group and sum the data using nest():

```
    var expensesCount = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.SKU; })
        .rollup(function(v) { return {
        "Product Title" : v[0]["Product Title"],
        "Monthly units": d3.sum(v, function(d) { return +d["Monthly units"];}),
        "Weekly units": d3.sum(v, function(d) { return +d["Weekly units"];})
        }; })
        .entries(data);
```

this will give you this json:

`[{"key":"PRD101","value":{"Product Title":"Product One","Monthly units":11,"Weekly units":14}},{"key":"PRD102","value":{"Product Title":"Product Two","Monthly units":10,"Weekly units":3}},{"key":" PRD103","value":{"Product Title":"Product Three","Monthly units":15,"Weekly units":10}},{"key":"PRD201","value":{"Product Title":"Product OneAndTwo","Monthly units":30,"Weekly units":5}}]`

Its prob easier to do the above first, then just loop through expenses Count and create a row for each object filtering out the unwanted objects.

You should clean up your data first and it will make this more straightforward. I used this as a test input..

```
 Product Title,SKU,Monthly units,Weekly units
 Product One,PRD101,5,2
 Product Two,PRD102,10,3
 Product Three, PRD103, 15, 10
 Product OneAndTwo,PRD201, 30, 5
 Product One,PRD101, 6, 12
```

Comment: I added the rollup values to the code in the codepen example, and I don't see any difference in the table or in the console.log file.  What am I missing?

Comment: you are not using the array. you need to change it here rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(expensesCount )
    .enter()
    .append('tr');

also, you will need to refactor how each cell is populated from the data...